# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x^2+y^2+z^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{xy+yz+zx}{x^2+y^2+z^4}$$

In order to calculate this limit, I did:

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\left(y\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+z^4}+z\frac{y}{x^2+y^2+z^4}+x\frac{z}{x^2+y^2+z^4}\right)$$

then, in each of these terms, one part is limited by $1$, and the other goes to $0$, then the entire thing goes to $0$

Am I rigth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=nx$, $z=mx$. So,
$$
\frac{xy+yz+xz}{x^2 + y^2 + z^4} = \frac{n+nm+m}{1 + n^2 + m^4x^2}.
$$
Limit depends on $n$ and $m$; so, it doesn't exists.

Comment: but is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Unfortunately no. At first, limits doesn't exists. Moreover, you said “one part is limited by $1$”. It's not true. Let $y=0$. Then abs of limit is $|xz/(x^2 + z^4)|\le |xz|/(2|xz^2|) = 1/2|z|$